# how can I know that particular words exist in a string or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, coffeescript, reactjs

I made array storing name of 5 different colors. So for example if string is "Bear is black and polar is white". Then I want to display that there are some color names in a string. But I can't do it as I am just a beginner & I know just basics of javascript. Now I am developing just small application that displays that there is color name in text or not. I thought that this will be a good way of learning. I am spinning my heads off since last 6 hours but now I gave up. Would anybody please help ? Pardon my indentation as I have wrote the code in hurry.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 function getNumber(){
  var colors = ["black","blue","green","yellow","white"];
  var getstring = document.getElementById("tobechecked");
        var splitter = getstring.split(" ");
        var i;
        var j;
        for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
          for(j=0,j<splitter.length;j++){
            if(splitter[j]==colors[i]){
            alert("colors exists");
            return true;
            }
            else
            {
              alert("colors don't exists");  
              return false;
                 }
          }
        }
  

 }

</script>
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="tobechecked">
</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="getNumber()"> Check !</button>
```

Comment: The typo in `spliiter[j]` may be at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check a string exists in another string

it'll return `-1` if `index` not found

like this

```
var colors = ["black","blue","green","yellow","white"];
var getstring = document.getElementById("tobechecked");

for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
{
   if(getstring.value.indexOf(colors[i])>-1){
      // exists 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function getNumber(){
  var colors = ["black","blue","green","yellow","white"],
      string = document.getElementById("tobechecked").innerText,
      i,length = colors.length;

  for( i=0; i < length; i++ ) {

    if( string.indexOf( colors[i] ) !== -1 ) {

      alert("colors exists");
      return true;

    }

  }

  alert("color doesn't exist");
  return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a syntax error, plus you were returning from the function as soon as you did any test. You can return as soon as you find a color, but if you don't find one, you need to keep checking and only return failure at the end.

```js
function getNumber() {
  var colors = ["black", "blue", "green", "yellow", "white"];
  var getstring = document.getElementById("tobechecked").value;
  var splitter = getstring.split(" ");
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < splitter.length; j++) {
      console.debug("Compare", splitter[j], colors[i]);
      if (splitter[j] == colors[i]) {
        alert("Color found");
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  alert("Color not found");
  return false;

}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="tobechecked">
</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="getNumber()">Check !</button>
```